# What is the right way to increase the input size on navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, navbar, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to write the following navbar on bootstrap (version 4), however, I'd like to know how can I increase the size of the input as shows below:
[image]

My code below:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-white navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/images/img.png" >
      </a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <div class="search_icon">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg input_search" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="What do you remember? Person, organization, place or keyword">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="responsiveNavbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="responsiveNavbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a bigger search box you can add the class `"input-group-lg`" to the div the `<input>` tag is in. As in:

```
 <div class="search_icon input-group-lg">
   <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg input_search" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="What do you remember? Person, organization, place or keyword">
 </div>
```

You can see the result in here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/del_cueto/pLhseuea/2/

Personally I think the size of the box in your image looks just fine, I would only change the size of the text by using another bootstrap class or even inline CSS styling such as in :

```
style = "font-size: 24px;"
```